# Vertical-align: middle not working?

Tags: html, css

Why isn't the `vertical-align: middle;` not working on my h1? The `ul` isn't aligning with the `h1` and it should.

```css
#logo {
 color: white;
 display: inline;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

ul {
 padding: 20px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

#title {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-size: 50px;
 top: 100px;

}

#navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 600px;
}

li {
 float: right;
 display: inline;
}

li a {
 display: inline;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
   <h1 id="logo">Jordan Baron</h1>
   <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
  </ul>

  <h1 id="title">Freelance Web Developer</h1>
 </div>
```

Comment: (1) You shouldn't put an `h1` as a child of a `ul`. [That's invalid HTML.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) (2) The [`vertical-align` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) applies only to inline-level and table-cell elements.

Comment: Typically there's only on `h1` per page. Semantically it doesn't make any sense to put your name in that unordered list.

Comment: Then what should I use instead?

Comment: a div with a class for example

Comment: Instead of multiple `h1`? Maybe make the second one an `h2` if appropriate, or use a `div`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `vertical-align` only applies to `inline` and `table-cell` elements, not block-level elements.

In order to have your links line up with your header, you need to assign a `line-height` equal to the height of the header element (35.33px):

```
li {
  line-height: 35.33px;
}
```

```css
#logo {
  color: white;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul {
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

#title {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  top: 100px;
}

#navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

li {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  line-height: 35.33px;
}

li a {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <h1 id="logo">Jordan Baron</h1>
    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
  </ul>

  <h1 id="title">Freelance Web Developer</h1>
</div>
```

It's also worth noting that having a `<h1>` element as a child of `<ul>` is invalid syntax. Only `<li>` elements shouold be a child of `<ul>`. What you should do is bring the title out of the `<ul>`, and float the entire `<ul>` element to the right.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ready for a bit of a mind flip?

Here comes FLEXBOX! This could be done "better" but I didn't want to change your html structure: https://jsfiddle.net/ohbffjjm/

```css
#navbar {
  background-color: pink;
}

#logo {
  margin-right: 150px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li a {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">

  <ul>
    <h1 id="logo">Jordan Baron</h1>
    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

And a `flexbox` solution with a few html improvements and improvisations.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  color: white;
  background: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 );
}

ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

header,
ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

h1,
h2 {
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

h1 {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
}

li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 350ms ease-in-out;
}
li a:hover {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<header>
    
      <h1 id="logo">Jordan Baron</h1>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
    
</header>
<main>
    <h2>Freelance Web Developer</h2>
</main>
```